# How to create a class template including class in .h and two .cpp files?

Tags: c++

My aim to create a very simple class template. I can do it in one .cpp file, but I insist on having the same class defined in .h file, its method in .cpp file and finally execute it in .cpp (main) and have some troubles.

So, in `class.h` I have what follows:

```
#include<iostream>

using namespace std;


template <class T>
class templateClass {
    T x, y;
public:
    templateClass(T, T); // constructor
    T bigger();
};
```

On the hand in `methods.cpp` there is:

```
#include<iostream>
#include"class.h"

using namespace std;


template <class T>
templateClass <T> ::templateClass(T a, T b) {
    x = a;
    y = b;
}

template <class T>
T templateClass<T>::bigger() {
    return (x > y ? x : y);
}
```

Finally in `main.cpp` I have

```
#include<iostream>
#include"class.h"

using namespace std;



int main() 
{
    templateClass<int> obj(12, 47);

    return 0;
}
```

In the end, I obtain an error unresolved external symbol "public: __thiscall templateClass::templateClass(int,int)" (??0?$templateClass@H@@QAE@HH@Z) referenced in function _main templateClass ...

Can you help me with explaing what is wrong and why the same works if put everything in one .cpp file without seperating?

Comment: You might insist but templates don't work that way. You're either going to have to put all the template code in a header file or give up on templates (or even C++).

Comment: Thank you for that, I thougt that class template can be "separated" the same way as normal classes.

Comment: I think it surprises everyone when they realise that they can't.

Comment: If you only have some fixed types that you will use with your template, then you can seperate them. See the question and answer (keyword: explicit template instantiation)

Comment: I recommend you to split your code in .h and .hpp, the .h containing the prototypes of your templated class, and the .hpp containing the implementation of your templated class.